# How do I elegantly str_detect across multiple columns and populating new columns conditionally

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr, across

As you can see, I'm dealing with some serious dirty data. This code works, but looks a bit clunky. Is there a more efficient and dynamic way to achieve the final results without so much coding?

I had to do this in stages where first to flag the content type, and utilizing the content type to populate them into respective column types.

appreciate your help

```r
#load library
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

#create sample data
df <- tibble(c1 = c('9996155', '4001096', '4001525', '4000590','2020-01-23', '2019-12-23', '2020-01-20', '2019-12-08'),
             c2 = c('4001902', '5000009', '2020-01-23', '2019-12-23', '2020-01-20', '2019-12-08', '4000461', '4000311'),
             c3 = c('W-7', 'W-8', 'W-9', 'W-2', 'W-1', 'W-1','3.527E+20', '3.498E+20'),
             c4 = c('B09/20', 'B04/20', 'B05/20', 'B10/20', 'B06/20',  '3.408E+20', '3.229E+20', '3.225E+20')
             )
```

The data looks like this

```
> df
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  c1         c2         c3        c4       
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr>    
1 9996155    4001902    W-7       B09/20   
2 4001096    5000009    W-8       B04/20   
3 4001525    2020-01-23 W-9       B05/20   
4 4000590    2019-12-23 W-2       B10/20   
5 2020-01-23 2020-01-20 W-1       B06/20   
6 2019-12-23 2019-12-08 W-1       3.408E+20
7 2020-01-20 4000461    3.527E+20 3.229E+20
8 2019-12-08 4000311    3.498E+20 3.225E+20
```

I have done something like this for getting it in shape

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(#flag them now to allow next step for data population
    starts_with('c'),
    ~ case_when(
      is.na(.) ~ NA_character_,
      str_detect(., regex('(^20[1,2][0-9]\\-)|(\\/20[1,2][0-9]$)')) ~ 'date',
      str_detect(., regex('\\d\\.\\d{3}[eE][+-]\\d{2}+')) ~ 'numericScientificNotation',
      str_detect(.,regex('(^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}\\/2[0-1]{1}$)|(^[A-Z]{1,2}\\-\\d.*[a-zA-Z]*$)|(^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2})|(^[A-Z][0-9]$)')) ~ 'batches',
      str_detect(., regex('^-?\\d+$')) ~ 'integers',
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ),
    .names = paste0('test', "_{col}")
  )) %>% #casewhen to populate new columns
  mutate(integer = case_when(test_c1 == 'integers' ~ c1,
                             test_c2 == 'integers' ~ c2,
                             test_c3 == 'integers' ~ c3,
                             test_c4 == 'integers' ~ c4),
         date = case_when(test_c1 == 'date' ~ c1,
                             test_c2 == 'date' ~ c2,
                             test_c3 == 'date' ~ c3,
                             test_c4 == 'date' ~ c4),
         batches = case_when(test_c1 == 'batches' ~ c1,
                               test_c2 == 'batches' ~ c2,
                               test_c3 == 'batches' ~ c3,
                               test_c4 == 'batches' ~ c4),
         numericScientificNotation = case_when(test_c1 == 'numericScientificNotation' ~ c1,
                               test_c2 == 'numericScientificNotation' ~ c2,
                               test_c3 == 'numericScientificNotation' ~ c3,
                               test_c4 == 'numericScientificNotation' ~ c4)
         ) %>% 
  select(9:12) #this is all that i need
```

Require only this organized output.

Thanks!

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  integer date       batches numericScientificNotation
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>                    
1 9996155 NA         W-7     NA                       
2 4001096 NA         W-8     NA                       
3 4001525 2020-01-23 W-9     NA                       
4 4000590 2019-12-23 W-2     NA                       
5 NA      2020-01-23 W-1     NA                       
6 NA      2019-12-23 W-1     3.408E+20                
7 4000461 2020-01-20 NA      3.527E+20                
8 4000311 2019-12-08 NA      3.498E+20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to simplify this and reduce repetition :

```
library(dplyr)

regex_list <- list(date = '(^20[1,2][0-9]\\-)|(\\/20[1,2][0-9]$)', 
                  numericScientificNotation = '\\d\\.\\d{3}[eE][+-]\\d{2}+', 
                  batches = '(^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}\\/2[0-1]{1}$)|(^[A-Z]{1,2}\\-\\d.*[a-zA-Z]*$)|(^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2})|(^[A-Z][0-9]$)', 
                  integers = '^-?\\d+$')


purrr::imap_dfc(regex_list, function(x, y) 
                  df %>%
                    mutate(across(.fns = ~ifelse(str_detect(.x, x), .x, NA))) %>%
                    transmute(!!y := do.call(coalesce, .)))

#  date       numericScientificNotation batches integers
#  <chr>      <chr>                     <chr>   <chr>   
#1 NA         NA                        W-7     9996155 
#2 NA         NA                        W-8     4001096 
#3 2020-01-23 NA                        W-9     4001525 
#4 2019-12-23 NA                        W-2     4000590 
#5 2020-01-23 NA                        W-1     NA      
#6 2019-12-23 3.408E+20                 W-1     NA      
#7 2020-01-20 3.527E+20                 NA      4000461 
#8 2019-12-08 3.498E+20                 NA      4000311
```

Comment: Your answers always amuse me Ronak.  +1.  Thanks for enlightening

Comment: Ronak there's one more thing that I'd to ask, if there's way to pass one lambda function into another?  Logic says there shouldn't be as how the arguments will be differentiated then, but I am not sure?

Comment: I am not sure either but I have never seen it and I agree with you how would we differentiate them? In such cases, I prefer to use an anonymous function to keep the logic clear.

Comment: @RonakShah That's a very elegantly written script. hope to reach this level some day. The only issue is, str_detect found multiple matches, and as result, it prompted "Can't combine `column1` <double> and `column2` <character>. The second answer below works because it has "values_fn = first". Is there anyway your masterpiece can accommodate duplicated values?

Comment: `coalesce` returns the first non-NA value in case of multiple matches. The issue I think is the classes are different for those multiple matches. Can you change the `mutate` line to `..mutate(across(.fns = ~as.character(ifelse(str_detect(.x, x), .x, NA)))) %>%...` and see if it helps?

Comment: @RonakShah That did it.

Answer (score 2):

You may also do this

```r
df <- data.frame(c1 = c('9996155', '4001096', '4001525', '4000590','2020-01-23', '2019-12-23', '2020-01-20', '2019-12-08'),
             c2 = c('4001902', '5000009', '2020-01-23', '2019-12-23', '2020-01-20', '2019-12-08', '4000461', '4000311'),
             c3 = c('W-7', 'W-8', 'W-9', 'W-2', 'W-1', 'W-1','3.527E+20', '3.498E+20'),
             c4 = c('B09/20', 'B04/20', 'B05/20', 'B10/20', 'B06/20',  '3.408E+20', '3.229E+20', '3.225E+20')
)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(!rowid) %>%
  mutate(new = case_when(str_detect(value, '(^20[1,2][0-9]\\-)|(\\/20[1,2][0-9]$)') ~ 'date',
                         str_detect(value, '\\d\\.\\d{3}[eE][+-]\\d{2}+') ~ 'numeric',
                         str_detect(value, '(^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}\\/2[0-1]{1}$)|(^[A-Z]{1,2}\\-\\d.*[a-zA-Z]*$)|(^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2})|(^[A-Z][0-9]$)') ~ 'Batches',
                         str_detect(value, '^-?\\d+$') ~ 'Integer',
                         TRUE ~ 'Other')) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid, names_from = new, values_from = value, values_fill = NA, values_fn = first)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   rowid Integer Batches date       numeric  
#>   <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>    
#> 1     1 9996155 W-7     <NA>       <NA>     
#> 2     2 4001096 W-8     <NA>       <NA>     
#> 3     3 4001525 W-9     2020-01-23 <NA>     
#> 4     4 4000590 W-2     2019-12-23 <NA>     
#> 5     5 <NA>    W-1     2020-01-23 <NA>     
#> 6     6 <NA>    W-1     2019-12-23 3.408E+20
#> 7     7 4000461 <NA>    2020-01-20 3.527E+20
#> 8     8 4000311 <NA>    2019-12-08 3.498E+20
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. this is an excellent solution. effective, and easy to understand for a newbie like me.

Comment: Glad that you liked it.  My intention to include it even after Ronak's elegant answer, was that only